# Why does Laravel dd only show two levels?

Tags: laravel

When I use `dd($myVar)` in Laravel the output only shows two levels.  Why is that?

The first level is shown expanded, and I can click to expand the second level.  The third level is simply summarised with something like `array:2` (in the case of any array with two elements).

EDIT:

I noticed that the output of `var_dump()` was similarly limited.  I changed the xdebug depth setting to 10, `ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 10)`, which fixed the problem in `var_dump`, but not `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `ctrl+click` to expand all children, you can even search values and variables using `ctrl+F`

If it doesn't suit you, you can create your own helper that depends on xdebug configuration settings. Add a new file "helpers.php" then  autoload it using composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
}
```

I used an anonymous class, you may create a dedicated class to cleanup/reuse code

```php
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner;
use Illuminate\Support\Debug\HtmlDumper;

function xdebug_dd(...$args)
{
    http_response_code(500);

    $obj = new class {
        public function dump($value)
        {
            if (class_exists(CliDumper::class)) {
                $dumper = new HtmlDumper;

                $dumper->dump((new VarCloner)->cloneVar($value), null, [
                    'maxDepth' => ini_get('xdebug.var_display_max_depth')
                ]);
            } else {
                var_dump($value);
            }
        }
    };


    foreach ($args as $x) {
        $obj->dump($x);
    }

    die(1);
}
```